# Wordpress theme activation issue

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi guys I'm working on a website I'm doing with wordpress I downloaded a theme that I imported into wordpress but when I activate it or try to preview it I get this error

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_shop() in /home/socooj5342/public_html/wp-content/themes/green-farm-elementor-pro/functions.php:52 Stack trace: #0 /home/socooj5342/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): green_farm_elementor_pro_scripts() #1 /home/socooj5342/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters() #2 /home/socooj5342/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action() #3 /home/socooj5342/public_html/wp-includes/script-loader.php(2156): do_action() #4 /home/socooj5342/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): wp_enqueue_scripts() #5 /home/socooj5342/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters() #6 /home/socooj5342/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action() #7 /home/socooj5342/public_html/wp-includes/general-template.php(3042): do_action() #8 /home/socooj5342/public_html/wp-content/themes/green-farm-elementor-pro/header.php(17): wp_head() #9 /home/socooj5342/public_html/wp-includes/template.php(7 in /home/socooj5342/public_html/wp-content/themes/green-farm-elementor-pro/functions.php on line 52`

what could be the cause of this problem and how to solve it please ?

Comment: Is your site having WooCommerce installed ?? (there are some themes which assume that you have installed WooCommerce)

Comment: Yes WooCommerce is already installed

Comment: this error appears when I try to preview the theme but when I activate the theme there is the loader displayed for a few seconds then it is a blank page